# Paramiko - reusing existing SSH handle causes EOF exception

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, paramiko

I open a SSH connection to a host and save the ssh handle to use it throughout the code. This is working perfectly except when I do not use the ssh handle for a long time. Here is a short code snippet that demonstrates what is happening.

I use `get_ssh_handle_pxe` to ssh to my host and save the ssh handle. Next time I call this method, we check if ssh handle is active and return the ssh handle rather than connecting once again to the host. The problem here is when I wait a long time between the two `ssh_handle_pxe.exec_command`, the second invocation throws EOF exception.

My question is, I am already checking in `get_ssh_handle_pxe` to make sure the ssh handle is active before returning it. Can ssh connection be active, but ssh channel is broken? do I need to check the channel separately? If the server is timing me out for inactivity, then I should be able to catch it with `is_ssh_active`. What am I missing here?

```
    ssh_handle_pxe = get_ssh_handle_pxe()

    (_, stdout, stderr) = ssh_handle_pxe.exec_command('ls -ltr')
    if stdout.channel.recv_exit_status() != 0:
        log.error("cannot run command: %s", stderr.read().decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
        sys.exit(2)

    # waiting for a long time - ~ 2 hours

    ssh_handle_pxe = get_ssh_handle_pxe()

    (_, stdout, stderr) = ssh_handle_pxe.exec_command('ls -ltr')  <--- EOF exception
    if stdout.channel.recv_exit_status() != 0:
        log.error("cannot run command: %s", stderr.read().decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
        sys.exit(2)


    def get_ssh_handle_pxe(self):

        if self.ssh_handle_pxe and is_ssh_active(self.ssh_handle_pxe):
            return self.ssh_handle_pxe

        try:
            ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
            ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            ssh.connect(self.pxe_server, username=self.username)
        except Exception as E:
            log.error("cannot connect to the PXE server %s: %s", self.pxe_server, E)
            sys.exit(2)

        self.ssh_handle_pxe = ssh

        return self.ssh_handle_pxe


    def is_ssh_active(client):

        if not client:
            return False

        try:
            transport = client.get_transport()
            if not transport:
                return False
            active = transport.is_active()
            if not active:
                return False
            # if is_active() returns True, we
            # need to also check send_ignore()
            transport.send_ignore()
            return True
        except EOFError:
            # connection is closed
            return False
```

From the call stack of the second exec_command invocation, I can see this:

[image]

Update: I enabled SSH debug in paramiko. During the ~2 hour waiting, I can see these debug messages keeps printing on the console,

```
DEBUG: [chan 2] Unhandled channel request "keepalive@openssh.com"
DEBUG: Received global request "keepalive@openssh.com"
DEBUG: Rejecting "keepalive@openssh.com" global request from server.
DEBUG: [chan 2] Unhandled channel request "keepalive@openssh.com"
DEBUG: Received global request "keepalive@openssh.com"
DEBUG: Rejecting "keepalive@openssh.com" global request from server.
DEBUG: [chan 2] Unhandled channel request "keepalive@openssh.com"
DEBUG: Received global request "keepalive@openssh.com"
DEBUG: Rejecting "keepalive@openssh.com" global request from server.
DEBUG: [chan 2] Unhandled channel request "keepalive@openssh.com"
```

Update2: I noticed that after calling the second exec_command, I get this:

```
Socket exception: Connection reset by peer (104).
```

This is interesting becuase `is_ssh_active` returned True!

Comment: As with all TCP/IP connections, you in general might not be able to tell if the connection is live, until you actually try to use it.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl SSH uses TCP under the hood. If TCP connection is broken then higher layer protocol (in this case SSH) should notice it. Right? How come the SSH protocol is not notified. Probably is_active() has a different meaning.